# Microsoft Bitlocker and TPM

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

I'm planning to buy a HP Envy 15-ep0813 computer, but I've spent hours trying to understand if that has TPM-like support so that I don't need to enter a passowrd prelogon, which for me is a must. I sadly cannot get hold of the HP support either, so turning to this forum instead.

It has the Intel® Core™ i7-10750H-processor, but cannot see if it has the necessary technology for the TPM-like-function (as it does not seem to have a physical TPM module). https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201837/intel-core-i7-10750h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html

Anyone have experience on how this works in practise?

Comment: Processor doesn’t determine if your laptop has a TPM module.  Contact HP to determine that

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. If a TPM is present it is mandatory that it can be enabled/disabled and cleared in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The TPM chip must be installed on the motherboard, separate from the CPU.

The policy by HP is not to include TPM with consumer desktops or notebooks.
Only business models come with it.

Your model is a consumer notebook, so doesn't have TPM.
(No wonder that you can't find TPM mentioned anywhere in connection
with it...)

Comment: This policy that you speak of is either false, or HP have changed it. This laptop does, in fact, have a TPM.

Answer (score 0):

This laptop does in fact come with a TPM and also BitLocker drive encryption; ignore the other answers, they are false.

How do I know this? Because I own this laptop myself.